# Why do I get a PHP date.timezone Warning each time I open the Terminal on MAC OS X?

Tags: php, macos, datetime, terminal

why do I get the following PHP warning each time I open the Terminal.app on OS X?

> Last login: Mon Dec 22 11:53:25 on ttys000
>
> PHP Warning:  Unknown: It
> is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are
> *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
> methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
> misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
> now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown
> on line 0
>
> machine:~ user$

I have noticed this only today, previously I didn't have this Warning displayed.
I have PHP date.timezone set inside the php.ini:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; Will be changed by MAMP to system timezone
date.timezone = "Europe/Moscow"
```

This directive is inside the php.ini located at **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini**, which is the one PHP configuration file my PHP uses from the CLI also:

```
machine:~ user$ which php
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php

machine:~ user$ php -i | grep "Configuration File"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini
```

I have also checked the php.ini of the pre-installed PHP inside /private/etc/php.ini (aliased by /etc/php.ini), and I have set the date.timezone directive there also.

So why do I still get this nasty warning?

Thank you for the attention!

EDIT: this is the output of `php --ini`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

It seems that the only loaded conf file is the php.ini of MAMP, but why do I keep obtaining that warning when I start the terminal?

Comment: Run `php --ini` to see maybe you have some additional `ini` files loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It was this line inside the .bash_profile in my *home* folder:

```
export PHP_API_VER=`php -i | grep 'PHP Extension =' | grep -oE '[0-9]+'`
```

I use this variable to know which PHP API extension I am currently using. As this variable export was after this one:

```
PATH="$MAMP_PHP_BIN_FOLDER:$PATH"
```

Which adds the PHP bin folder (where the *php* command is located) to the PATH env var, I experienced that error because when opening Terminal.app the wrong **php** command was used I had to put PHP_API_VER export after the PATH one.

Then I asked myself "Why do I obtain that warning if I have both MAMP PHP and OS X pre-installed PHP .ini files with the date.timezone directive set?", and the answer was a `which php` when .bash_profile did load, which revealed:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

What?! I had another version of PHP installed I forgot about (I installed it with HomeBrew). So I checked the php.ini of that php command, added the date.timezone directive and everything is great and works now.

Bye!